# How to convert ArrayList<object> to String and vice versa

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I want to convert my `ArrayList<object>` to a **JSON** `String` and back to `ArrayList<object>`

But I really don't know how to do that :

Something like :

```
Convert
ArrayList<data> arrayData = new ArrayList<data>();
 JSONObject retObject = new JSONObject();
    retObject.put("data", new JSONArray(arrayData ));

    Return convert

idk...
```

Comment: Which library are you using ? It is a very straight forward job in GSON !

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037340/converting-jsonarray-to-arraylist

Comment: Are you sure you want a JSON string and not a JSON array?

Comment: i want to put my Arraylist into a Cookie which only supports strings

Comment: You should mention such details when asking the question the next time, at least then you provide an understandable context for your question. But while we're on this topic: you can just as easily translate the data into a string where you are creating the cookie, it does not necessarily have to happen before transmission of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider using a JSON library like Google's Gson library to store and retrieve objects as JSON strings. This is a lightweight library, well regarded and popular. It would be an ideal solution in your case with minimal work required. e.g.,

```
// How to store JSON string

Gson gson = new Gson();
// This can be any object. Does not have to be an arraylist.

String json = gson.toJson(myAppsArr);

// How to retrieve your Java object back from the string

Gson gson = new Gson();

DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(arrayString, ArrayList.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String listAsJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(oldList);
List<Object> newList= mapper.readValue(listAsJson ,new TypeReference<List<Object>>() {});
```

Comment: Not quite JSON, I don't think.

Comment: No worries, mate, just delete the response before you get voted down

Comment: I changed it to Jackson, could be?

Comment: I'm not going to vote it down, but personally, I prefer [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Comment: I use xstream for xml parsing and manipulating, in case of json it depends on project

Comment: To each their own, @hexin

Answer (score -1):

```
ArrayList<Product> arrayData = new ArrayList<Product>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

convert list to json object

```
String jsonCartList = gson.toJson(cartList);
```

convert  json to your list

```
List<Product> prodList = gson.fromJson(jsonCartList, Product.class);
```

Comment: Wouldn't the last line cause a type mismatch?