# How To Convert JSONArray To LinkedHashMap<String,String>?

Tags: java, json, linkedhashmap

I have a JSON Object in The Form

> {"pageId":1,"stgId":1,"userId":2,"requestStageId":0,"requestPageId":0,"answer":[{"qId":"6","ansValue":"1"},{"qId":"11","ansValue":"10"}]}

I receive the data as :

```
long uid = (long)inputJsonObj.get("userId");
long stgid = (long)inputJsonObj.get("stgId");
long pgid = (long)inputJsonObj.get("pageId");
JSONArray answer_Array =    (JSONArray) inputJsonObj.get("answer");
```

ie, answer_Array conatins :

> [{"qId":"6","ansValue":"1"},{"qId":"11","ansValue":"10"}]

Now I need To Convert the JSONArray **answer_Array** To LinkedHashMap, where **qid** will be the **key** and **ansValue** will be the **Value**.

How can This be done ?

Comment: This won't give you the expected datastructure for free, but you'll be able to build it yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17037364/1939607

Comment: Are you using Jackson or any json lib for parsing json?

Comment: @iNan : I am using org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser

Comment: if you ll use `Hashmap` then problem ll be there because, there can be multiple record whose key name is `qId`, so when we add in `Hashmap` it will `overwrite the existing one` whose key value in `qId`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the Array and use this method

```
public static Map parseStringToMap(String param)
    {
        Map result  =   new HashMap<String,String>();
        if(param!=null)
        {
            StringBuffer sb     =   new StringBuffer(param);    
            try
            {
                String str  =   sb.substring(1, sb.length()-1);
                String[] srArray    =   str.split(",");
                String tempStr  =   null;
                for(int i=0;srArray!=null && i<srArray.length;i++)
                {
                    tempStr =   srArray[i];
                    if(tempStr!=null && tempStr.contains(":"))
                    {
                        String[] keyVal =   tempStr.split(":");
                        if(keyVal.length>1)
                            result.put(keyVal[0], keyVal[1]);
                        else
                            result.put(keyVal[0], "");
                    }

                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("In JSONConverter: Issue while parsing the JSON => "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a helper method which takes answer array as input and returns map of question and answer.

```
private static Map<String, String> getHashMapFromJson(JSONArray answer_Array) {

        Map<String, String> qaMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = answer_Array.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            JSONObject value = iterator.next();

            qaMap.put((String) value.get("qId"), (String) value.get("ansValue"));
        }

        return qaMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can do something like **(To Avoid Overwrite)**:

```
Map result  =   new HashMap<String,String>();
for( int i = 0 ; i < jArray.length() ; i++ ){
       JSONObject object = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
       result.put(object.getString("qId"), object.getString("ansValue"));
}

for (Object variableName: result.keySet()){
       System.out.println(String.valueOf(variableName));
       System.out.println(result.get(variableName));
}
```

Main Reason I have done `"qId"+i` is that you want data in Hashmap so if the same key then it ll `overwrite the already exist`. and you want `qId` as key.

It's better to use `List` instead of it and make one class of data it will work perfect.

**OR YOU CAN TRY**

My code **(With List)**:

```
static class KeyVal{
    String qkey; String qval; String akey; String aval;
    public String getQkey() {return qkey;}
    public void setQkey(String qkey) { this.qkey = qkey;}
    public String getQval() {return qval;}
    public void setQval(String qval) {this.qval = qval;}
    public String getAkey() {return akey;}
    public void setAkey(String akey) {this.akey = akey;}
    public String getAval() {return aval;}
    public void setAval(String aval) {this.aval = aval;}
}
List<KeyVal> data = new ArrayList<>();
KeyVal key;
for( int i = 0 ; i < ja.length() ; i++ ){
    JSONObject object = ja.getJSONObject(i);
    key = new KeyVal();
    key.setQkey("qId"); key.setQval(object.getString("qId"));
    key.setAkey("ansValue"); key.setAval(object.getString("ansValue"));
    data.add(key);
}
for( int i = 0 ; i < data.size() ; i++ ){
    System.out.println(data.get(i).getQkey() + " : " + data.get(i).getQval());
    System.out.println(data.get(i).getAkey() + " : " + data.get(i).getAval());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method Works For me ->

```
 /* Extract The JSONArray and insert The qid and ansValue into the HashMap<String,String> */

       JSONArray answer =    (JSONArray) inputJsonObj.get("answer");                                   
               JSONParser parser3 = new JSONParser();
               JSONObject jsonObject3 = null;
               for(int i=0;i< answer.size();i++){                      
                    System.out.println(answer.get(i).toString());
                    Object obj3 = parser3.parse(answer.get(i).toString());
                    jsonObject3 = (JSONObject) obj3;
                    String qid = (String) jsonObject3.get("qId");
                    String ansValue = (String) jsonObject3.get("ansValue");                     
                    map.put(qid, ansValue);
               }
```

Comment: What is the size of map ?  Is it overwrite ? can you print map data ?