# Storing JSON Response in an array

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, gson

I am trying to store a json array response into an arraylist. Here is what the JSON response looks like:

```
"identityList":{
    "identity":[
        {
            "firstName":"MICHAEL",
            "lastName":"JAMESON",
            "gender":"MALE",
            "dateOfBirth":"1961-05-18T00:00:00.000+0000",
        },
        {
            "firstName":"KELLY",
            "lastName":"JAMESON",
            "gender":"FEMALE",
            "dateOfBirth":"1951-04-01T00:00:43.000+0000",
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the `Identity` class:

```
public class Identity {
    /** The first name. */
    private String firstName;

    /** the middleName. */
    private String middleName;

    /** the lastName. */
    private String lastName;

    /** the dateOfBirth. */
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    public Identity(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Based on what I've found on other SO posts like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578493/how-to-store-json-response-in-an-array-list) I wrote this function to parse it:

```
public static <T> T getResponseObjectAsArray(String resourceResponse, String jsonObject, final Class<T> responseClass) {
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<responseClass>>(){}.getType();
    JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resourceResponse).getJSONArray(jsonObject);
    return gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, listType);
}
```

And calling it like this:

```
getResponseObjectAsArray(resourceResponse, "identityList", Identity.class)
```

With `resourceResponse` being the json response in a string format. But I get a syntax error with the `getResponseObjectAsArray` method that says:

```
Error:(39, 44) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class responseClass
```

I'm trying to parametrize the list with whatever class passed into the method because it could be a list of many other types and not just `Identity`. What am i doing wrong here?

**Edit 1:** Tried the solution of `List<T>` and got this error now:

```
Error:(41, 20) java: no suitable method found for fromJson(org.json.JSONArray,java.lang.reflect.Type)
    method com.google.gson.Gson.<T>fromJson(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to java.lang.String))
    method com.google.gson.Gson.<T>fromJson(java.lang.String,java.lang.reflect.Type) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to java.lang.String))
    method com.google.gson.Gson.<T>fromJson(java.io.Reader,java.lang.Class<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to java.io.Reader))
    method com.google.gson.Gson.<T>fromJson(java.io.Reader,java.lang.reflect.Type) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to java.io.Reader))
    method com.google.gson.Gson.<T>fromJson(com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader,java.lang.reflect.Type) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader))
    method com.google.gson.Gson.<T>fromJson(com.google.gson.JsonElement,java.lang.Class<T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to com.google.gson.JsonElement))
    method com.google.gson.Gson.<T>fromJson(com.google.gson.JsonElement,java.lang.reflect.Type) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (argument mismatch; org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to com.google.gson.JsonElement))
```

**Edit 2:** Here's another attempt at parametrizing a list object:

```
public static <T> List<T> getResponseObjectAsArray(String resourceResponse, String jsonObject, Class<T> responseClass) {
    JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resourceResponse).getJSONObject("identityList").getJSONArray(jsonObject);
    return gson.fromJson(jsonResponse.toString(), List<responseClass>);
}
```

I just hardcoded the identityList string for now but later I'll make it as user input. But I'm still unable to parametrize the list inside of the `fromJson` call. I'm getting an `Expression expected` error.

Comment: TypeToken<List<responseClass>>(){}.getType(); where is the responseClass defined? Either use a wildcard or exact class definition

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840483/how-to-have-java-method-return-generic-list-of-any-type) I figured out how to implement what I want. Here's the code now:

```
public static <T> List<T> getResponseObjectAsArray(String resourceResponse, String jsonObject, Class<T> responseClass) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    try {
        list.add(responseClass.getConstructor().newInstance());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resourceResponse).getJSONObject("identityList").getJSONArray(jsonObject);
    return gson.fromJson(jsonResponse.toString(), list.getClass());
}
```

There's still stuff to fix like proper error handling and not hard coding the getJson value.

Answer (score 0):

The line giving you the issue is this one:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<responseClass>>(){}.getType();
```

Since responseClass is an object. Type checking in Java is a static thing, so it does not accept a class object as a specialization parameter for List. You could fix this by simply changing it to the statically known type T:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
```

**Edit**

getResponseObjectAsArray should return an array of T, not a single element T. The problem is in getting the class of an array of generic types, due to type erasure.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] getArray(String json, String field, final Class<T> clazz) {
    JSONArray array = new JSONObject(json).getJSONArray(field);
    try {
        Class<T[]> arrayClass = (Class<T[]>) Class.forName("[L" + clazz.getName() + ";");
        return gson.fromJson(array, arrayClass);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // If T.class exists, then T[].class should also exist, so this should never be reached
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's java's weird way of [specifying an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085889/l-array-notation-where-does-it-come-from).

Comment: I tried this and I got the same error respones as above. `No suitable method found for fromJson(org.json.JSONArray, java.lang.class<T[]>)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102923/discussion-between-andrew-williamson-and-richard).

Answer (score 0):

String jsonResultString = sb.toString();
 ArrayList crawlerList = gson.fromJson(jsonResultString, new TypeToken>() {}.getType());

or try read this 
http://androidengineer.weebly.com/tutorials/json-to-gson-to-java-with-httpurlconnection-in-android
@SerializedName(*firstName*)
private String firstName;

```
@SerializedName("firstName")
private String middleName;

@SerializedName("lastName")
private String lastName;

@SerializedName("gender")
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
```

end ect....