# Convert JSONObject to List<JSONObject> or a String to List<JSONObject>

Tags: java, json

I submit a query from my Java application, which upon running on Elasticsearch server returns the result in the form of a string. I want the result as a list of `JSONObject` objects. I can convert the string to a `JSONObject` using  `JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseString)`.

Is there any method by which I can get this in the form of a `List<JSONObject>`?

Comment: @trololo : The solution here does not give the answer to my question . I just need a simple, direct conversion to List<JSONObject> , not an array .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using JSONObject you may use [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html). If you really need to convert it to a List you may do something like:

```
List<JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
try {
    int i;
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(string);
    for (i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
        list.add(array.getJSONObject(i);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Is there not a method specifically for List<JSONObject> and not ArrayList<JSONObject> ?

Comment: @AishwaryaGarg I have updated the answer. List<?> is just an interface.

Comment: I get the error that " The method add(org.json.JSONObject) in the type List<JSONObject> is not applicable for the arguments (com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject) " upon using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer of your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17037364/1979882

```
ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
if (jArray != null) { 
   for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
    listdata.add(jArray.get(i).toString());
   } 
}
```

Comment: Is there not a method specifically for List<JSONObject> and not ArrayList<JSONObject> ?

Comment: List is an interface. You can use List<String> listdata instead of ArrayList<String> listdata

Answer (score 0):

This method is really easy and works too

```java
try {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(THESTRINGHERE);
    String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObject);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.toJSONArray(new JSONArray(names));

    ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();     
    JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)jsonArray; 
    if (jArray != null) { 
       for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
           listdata.add(jArray.get(i).toString());
       } 
    } 
    //  System.out.println(listdata);


} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```