# Why Android change 'compile' to 'implementation' configuration in Gradle dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

As seen in Android Studio 3.0 (canary 3.0), we now add `depedencies` by declaring `implementation` instead of `compile` configuration.

```
// Before
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

// Currently
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

We can still use `compile`, but I would like to understand:

- What is the difference between `implementation` and `compile` configuration?
- Why do Android Gradle build change to use `implementation` as default?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems like `compile` has been deprecated and `api` or `implementation` should be used instead. According to [The Java Library Plugin - Gradle User Guide Version 3.5](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html):

> The `compile` configuration still exists but should not be used as it will not offer the guarantees that the `api` and `implementation` configurations provide.

Answer (score 31):

Thanks to the really useful link from @petter, I would like to add a summary as following.

It means that `Android Gradle build` starts to use the `java-library` plugin instead of its previous `java` plugin. This plugin introduces the `exposed API` concept with two `configuration` to declare dependencies.

1. **api**

> should be used to declare dependencies which are exported by the
>   library API

For example, in a case that you are building a Java (or Android) library which is used by other apps. If you use any third-party library and you want to expose its API to your library's consumer also, you should declare like this.

```
api 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
```

2. **implementation**

> should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the
>   component.

When developing Android app, our `app` module is the end point which does not need to expose any part externally. `implementation` should be used.

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
```

**The previous `compile` configuration works the same as `api`**. The `implementation`, however, brings the following benefits.

- dependencies do not leak into the compile classpath of consumers
  anymore, so you will never accidently depend on a transitive
  dependency
- faster compilation thanks to reduced classpath size
- less recompilations when implementation dependencies change:
  consumers would not need to be recompiled
- cleaner publishing: when used in conjunction with the new
  maven-publish plugin, Java libraries produce POM files that
  distinguish exactly between what is required to compile against the
  library and what is required to use the library at runtime (in other 
  words, don't mix what is needed to compile the library itself and
  what is needed to compile against the library).

Comment: This is much clear and easy to understand, thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: As - dependencies do not leak into the compile classpath of consumers anymore, so you will never accidentally depend on a transitive dependency


`@Quang - What if I am developing a library for Android applications where I want to ship this with few dependencies I have used inside the library?`