# Converting string to JSONArray, and then to list

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have String "[{...}]" and I want convert it to JSONArray, and then to `List list = new List` I was trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037340/converting-jsonarray-to-arraylist?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) solution, and this is my code

```
public void RestoreData()
{
    String toConvert = "[{...}]" // I don't place full String, but it's typical JSONArray, but in String
    ArrayList<myClass> listdata = new ArrayList<myClass>();
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject;
    if (jArray != null) {
        for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            listdata.add(jArray.getString(i));
        }
    }
}
```

And when I'm trying to compile this I get 2 errors:

- In `JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject;` I get error 'Incovertible types; cannot cast 'org.json.JSONObject' to 'org.json.JSONArray'.
- And second: in `listdata.add(jArray.getString(i));` I get error 'unhandled exception org.json.JSONException'.

I'm new in Java and I work with Json for the first time.

**EDIT**
A small truncated example of the Json string:

> [{"lootArmorGain":0,"lootBlockGain":0,"lootCost":93500,"lootCritGain":2,"lootCritPowerGain":0,"lootDamageAbsorptionGain":0,"lootDamageGain":0,
>   }]

Comment: can you place some sample data so that we can check it

Comment: @Alok what do you mean? Text of this String?

Comment: yes some part of string so that we can check it, if it is valid data or not.

Comment: Please give a small (truncated) example of the string you say is a "... typical JSONArray".

Comment: Now we need to know what `myClass` is. By-the-way in java naming convention methods do not use capitalization... however, Classes are capitalized.

Comment: I made a mistake. It's Object Array, and this is fragment of this String:[{"lootArmorGain":0,"lootBlockGain":0,"lootCost":93500,"lootCritGain":2,"lootCritPowerGain":0,"lootDamageAbsorptionGain":0,"lootDamageGain":0, }]

Comment: myClass is a class created by me: public class myClass() { public myClass(....) {  /*code */ }  /* code */ }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
public void RestoreData()
{
   try{
    String toConvert = "[{...}]" // I don't place full String, but it's typical JSONArray, but in String
    ArrayList<MyClass> listdata = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(toConvert); 

    if (jsonArray != null) {
       Gson gson = new Gson();
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            String json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
            MyClass obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
            listdata.add(obj);
        }
    }
    }catch(JSONException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To convert from JSONOject to your custom class use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), see above.

```
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
```

Note that your custom class need to have an empty constructor as well as getters and setters in order to make gson work.

Comment: i got again "unhandled exception org.json.jsonexception". on this code "JSONArray(toConvert)"

Comment: it means your String is probably a not valid json array as you said

Comment: Ohhh yea, sorry, i made mistake.. look at my question now. I want to conver to ArrayList<Object>

Comment: Now my code handles the exception, can you run it and tell us what the stack trace tells you the JSONExeption message?

Comment: I can run this, and it working, but now, how to convert this JSONArray to ArrayList<myClass> ?

Comment: I see, take a look at the edit, you'll need to use Gson

Comment: 'cannot resolve method 'fromJson(org.json.JSONObject'' on 'jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)', and '';'expected' on point between MyClass and class, and after class on ')' 'Indentifier expected'

Comment: instructions in for was made, but size of listdata = 0 :/    (btw i didn't vote down u xD)

Comment: No problem, some people don't understand that if they downvote someone it is polite to explain why :/

Comment: Could your post MyClass? It needs to have an empty constructor and getters and setters in order to Gson to work properly

Comment: Great :) Glad I could help you :)

Comment: I agree @LeviAlbuquerque. I just don't understand people down voting valid answers without at least saying why it was down voted. Maybe that person will eventually get up some courage to explain themselves! An Up vote to compensate.

Answer (score 1):

I think best approach will be using [Google Gson Library](https://github.com/google/gson).

```
String toConvert = "[{...}]"
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<myClass>>() {}.getType();
List<myClass> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(toConvert, listType);
```

You dont need to get each position manually.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity you can also use Jackson api

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory typeFactory = objectMapper.getTypeFactory();
List<SomeClass> someClassList = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString,typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, SomeClass.class));
```

Comment: How to use this? I must write something build.gradle? what?

Comment: you must add dependency of jackson api in your build.gralde  ( just like another dependency and use the above code )