# How to assign JSONArray to variable?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I have a problem :

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json);
List<String> list = (List<String>) data.getJSONArray("childrens");

for (String item : list) {
       Log.d("DEBUG", item);
}
```

I would like to assign `data.getJSONArray("childrens")` to a variable `list`, but I have an error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to
>   java.util.List

How can I do this?

I would like to iterate over JSON Array.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is, that the method `.getJSONArray(...)` returns an `org.json.JSONArray` object, **not** a `java.util.List` object, and casting the thing won't fix this. You need to create a JSONArray variable, assign to it the object returned from the method, and then use methods available to this object.

Comment: But how to iterate over JSONArray?

Comment: The [JSONArray API](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray) will tell you what methods you can use with this, but I'd look at using the `length()` and `get(int index)` methods to iterate through using a for loop.

Comment: Use JSONArray list = data.getJSONArray("childrens");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSONarray to ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037340/converting-jsonarray-to-arraylist)

Comment: You can iterate JSONArray just like any any array. for(int i = 0;i < list.length();++i){ String item = list.getString(i); }

Comment: In the future, please search for and study the API before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONObject` only contains `JSONArray`, not `List`. You have to transform it manually:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray jsonArray = data.getJSONArray("childrens");
for (Object o : jsonArray) {
    String child = (String)o;
    Log.d("DEBUG", child);
}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels [documentation](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html) states it for *latest* version on 2016.

Answer (score 3):

You can't `data.getJSONArray("childrens")` returns an object of type `org.json.JSONArray`.

However, you can iterate over a JSONArray :

```
    JSONArray jArray = data.getJSONArray("childrens");

    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jb = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.d("DEBUG", jb);
    }
```