# Kotlin JSONArray to MutableList<JSONObject>

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin, mutable

I am fairly new to Kotlin and I am currently dealing with JSON a lot.

I receive a JSON string from the server which I parse into `JSONArray` as below

```
var dataArray = JSONArray(String(resultVar!!))
```

But as far as I've seen `JSONArray` doesn't really give me enough capabilities to change it's data, it forces me to create a new `JSONArray`, if I'm not mistaken. So I thought I should use `MutableList<JSONObject>`, which seems good enough, but I can't find a way to parse JSONArray or the String into it.

How do I do this the easy way? Do I have to iterate through the JSONArray adding every single JSONObject one by one?

> As a side question, should I just stick to JSONArray? Is there a way to manipulate the data inside it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037340/converting-jsonarray-to-arraylist), there is no builtin method to convert `JSONArray` to `List`.
However, You can use Kotlin tricks to make the java code much shorter:

```
fun JSONArray.toMutableList(): MutableList<JSONObject> = MutableList(length(), this::getJSONObject)
```

Note that `JSONArray` may have values that are not `JSONObject` (but `JSONArray` for example). If you are not sure the array contains just object, use the following method:

```
fun JSONArray.toMutableList(): MutableList<Any> = MutableList(length(), this::get)
```

---

If you are using the `JSON-java` [library](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) and not the android one, then you can use [`JSONArray.toList()`](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/JSONArray.java#L1463) which returns a list you can modify.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!