# How to create a string list from a JSONArray?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a jsonArray object like the "Input" below. I would like the "Output". Could you help me ?

Input :

```
"["a", "b", "c", "d"]"
```

Output :

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"]

//i need a simple list of string
```

I have found a solution but it's too complex for a simple conversion....

```
        val errorFields = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("my_array")
                .join(",")
                .replace("\"", "")
                .split(",")
```

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037340/converting-jsonarray-to-arraylist But in Kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By manual parsing you can get a list of string from jsonArray by -

```
val list = ArrayList<String>()
repeat(jsonArray.length){
    list.add(jsonArray.getString(it))
}
```

If you are using parsing library gson than you can get a list of strings by -

```
val list = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), Array<String>::class.java)?.toList()
```

Comment: i enjoy your solution with gson

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so:

```
    val stringList : MutableList<String> = arrayListOf()
    jsonArray?.let {
        for (i in 0 until it.length()) {
            stringList.add(jsonArray.getString(i))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way in Koltin

`var str = "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\", \"d\"]"
 var items = Arrays.asList(str?.split("\\s*,\\s*")).flatten()`

`flatten` is needed as it returns a list of lists.